# visual studio 2012 opendialog stuck on default directory

Tags: visual-studio, openfiledialog

I am writing a windows forms based application on visual studio ultimate 2012. I put in an opendialog in order to open and read a file. Here's the code:-

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
Stream myStream = null;
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\" ;
openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;

if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    try
    {
        if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            using (myStream)
            {
                // Insert code to read the stream here.
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

}

But every time I try to run this, when I choose a file from the browser window, it shows me a filenotfound exception as it looks for the file in the default directory(located in Documents/VisualStudio/Projects/WindowsFormApplication/bin/debug/openFileDialog1), not in the directory I specified. Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the following line

```
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
```

This causes the current directory to be reset to the original directory once the dialog was closed.  It appears the `OpenFile` method is using a relative path and hence is attempting to open the file where the dialog started, not where it ended.

Try removing the `RestoreDirectory` setting and manually reset the path once you are through using the file